# How to use fink on macOS 10.14.4 Mojave

Tags: xcode, macos, fink

My macos is Mojave, 10.14.4, and Xcode has been fully updated. I completed the task this morning. Additionally, after I downloaded Xcode through App Store, a popup announced

> Install additional required components? Xcode requires additional components to support running and
>   debugging. Choose install to add required components.

and I fully complied. Finally I was able to open Xcode and the version is

> Xcode 10.2.1 (10E1001)

For extra measure, I rebooted the computer. But fink still will not function; see below.

```
> fink install jhead
Password:
Use 'fink reinstall fink' to switch distributions
from 10.13 to 10.14.
'install' operation not permitted.
> fink reinstall fink
Use 'fink reinstall fink' to switch distributions
from 10.13 to 10.14.
Information about 11530 packages read in 2 seconds.
Failed: 
The Xcode Command Line Tools need to be (re)installed. 
Execute 'sudo xcode-select --install' to obtain them.
Or you can get them via direct download from developer.apple.com
(free registration required) if you don't want to install Xcode.app.
> sudo xcode-select --install
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
> fink -V
Package manager version: 0.43.1
Distribution version: selfupdate-git Fri May 10 17:37:58 2019, 10.13, x86_64
Trees: local/main stable/main

Copyright (c) 2001 Christoph Pfisterer
Copyright (c) 2001-2016 The Fink Package Manager Team
This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU General Public License for more details.
>
```

How do I get fink to work?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Alexander Hansen, Ph.D., Fink User Liaison, on fink-beginners@lists.sourceforge.net:

> fink 0.43.1 won’t work on Mojave, period.  We really can’t make a fink release work on OS versions that are newer, so we
>   encourage people to update fink before updating the OS.
>
> You can download a fink version that will work from https://sourceforge.net/projects/fink/files/fink/0.44.1/fink_0.44.1-131_darwin-x86_64.deb/download , then from a terminal windowuse “sudo dpkg -i $HOME/Downloads/fink_0.44.1-131_darwin-x86_64.deb” to update it (replace $HOME/Downloads) with your actual download location.

This did the trick and I was subsequently able to install jhead.